Can't activate attack animation midair while pressing X key while holding W key and notGrounded
It works perfectly fine when the condition is only pressing the X key. The problems arose when I added to hold the W key. it works only 30% of the time.
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)
        {
            Attackpressed = true;
        }

        if (Attackpressed)
        {
            Attackpressed = false;
            if (!isAttacking)
            {
                isAttacking = true;
            }
            if (IsGrounded())
            {
              PlayAnimation(Attackup);
            }
            Invoke("AnimationStop",0.3f);
            
            {
              PlayAnimation(Attackupaway);
            }
            

            Invoke("AnimationStop",0.3f);
        }


while holding the w key and pressing the x key, and when it is not grounded, it activates the "attackupaway" animation. I don't want to add a transition to the animation because I have a really hard time when the logic gets complicated. Thank you

The PlayAnimation(Attackupaway) will always run, because there is no condition for the scope that it's in. The {} that surround it do nothing. What is the expected behavior? You might be missing an else?

The problem here is use of GetKeyDown.
Compare with GetKey.
GetKey() will return true in every frame that the key is held down while GetKeyDown() only returns true in the first frame that is is pressed, then false after that even if the key is still down - which it is rather often because the frames can, and do, happen multiple times in the moment we press a key.
https://community.gamedev.tv/t/getkey-vs-getkeydown/222468

hi there, after some testing it works fine with any other key eg E,D key. It doesnt work for W only so far. Is this a bug?

More likely not. You might have some other if (condition) { ... } check on the W key in your code. If yes, and depending on the type (GetKey() vs GetKeyDown()) you might never be reaching the code you posted. Add some Debug.Log statements to all your keydown/keypress checks so you can see what fires. It normally helps to number each one in a comment and then when outputting to the console log also add "if condition x executed" where x is the number. You can then correlate exactly which condition check is triggering behaviors (or lack thereof).
